# mysql select multiple rows, multi and/or

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select multiple rows from a mysql database based on the value of selected columns, I am new to php and sql so this might be something simple I just cannot seem to find anything that is similar to my situation. Here is the query I am running:

```
SELECT  COUNT(userid) AS numrows
FROM    orders
WHERE   (
        `dispatched` = 'no' 
        AND `orderstatus` = 'Complete'
        AND `category` = 'tosort'
        )
        OR
        (`category` = 'new')
```

This counts all fields when it should only show around 10.

Thanks,
David

Comment: Could you please do `SELECT *` instead of `SELECT COUNT(*)` and post a record which should not be counted, in your opinion?

Comment: Also, are you using some kind of an `ORM`? Curly braces will fail in pure `MySQL`, do you really have them in your query?

Comment: Hi Quassnoi,  the curly braces was just somthing I saw on another website I must admit I hadent seen them used before.

Comment: I will do the query now sorry I am a little new and slow at this...

Comment: @David: please post your query exactly as you submit it to `MySQL`. You current query wouldn't parse.

Comment: I have tried: select count(*) as numrows
from orders
where (dispatched = 'no' and orderstatus = 'Complete' and category = 'tosort')
   or (category = 'new');

Comment: this return 6 rows, one has orderstaus of Incomplete rather than Complete (should only be 5 rows in total

Comment: @David: in the future, please don't post the queries into comments, rather update your post. Please post the whole record which you think should not be returned.

Comment: Sorry Quassnoi I am new to this site, I will do this in future (Its very hard to keep up, Thank you all for the quick replys!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use brackets, use parentheses.  This works for me:

```
select count(*) as numrows
from orders
where (dispatched = 'no' and orderstatus = 'Complete' and category = 'tosort')
   or category = 'new';
```

Comment: Hi Brian, I did just try something simlar to this but as stated above it returns one to many results:  one has orderstaus of Incomplete rather than Complete

Comment: Do you have any other categories besides 'new' or 'tosort'?  If so, then you need to take all of them into account in your SQL. What is the contents of the category field for that record with an Incomplete orderstatus?

Comment: Hi Brian,Yes there is one more category other than the two mentioned I have posted a sample of the one that displays incorrectly above

Answer (score 0):

What's the error you get? Because looking at the code now, it seems okay.

You either want records that have "dispatched - no, orderstats - completer and category - tosrt" OR.. anything with 'category - new'.

Edit: Oh, longshot, maybe you need to replace { and } with ()

Comment: Hi Gerben sorry I missed your message, I did try this and It made the query work but the other people here are just helping me sort out another issue. Thank you for your help though I am one step closer! :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all very much for your quick replys, after playing around a bit more I managed to get this to work. Here it is if you anyone is reading this looking for the same answer:

```
SELECT COUNT(userid) AS numrows FROM orders WHERE (`dispatched` = 'no' AND `orderstatus` = 'Complete' AND `category` = 'tosort') OR (`dispatched` = 'no' AND `orderstatus` = 'Complete' AND `category` = 'new')
```

Thanks again!

Comment: This is a simpler way of doing the same thing:

select count(\*) as numrows
from orders
where dispatched = 'no' and orderstatus = 'Complete' and category in ('tosort','new');


If you just want to count the number of records returned in the result set, then it's better to use count(*). If you explicitly specify a field name as in count(fieldname), any records that contain nulls in that field will not be included in the count. Details at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count.

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for the information I have updated my script thats a much cleaner way of doing this.